# Не отображаются иконки

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, css, иконки

Сделал страницу на JQuery и всё отображалось корректно если я приклепляю .js и .css  с сайта разработчика. Но когда я скачал эти файлы и в head указал путь к ним, то перестали показываться все  иконки (delete, home, arrow-r и все остальные) а вместо их остаются "дырки". В чём проблема?

https://pp.vk.me/c616826/v616826182/e60/9fbA1cJzzlA.jpg

Comment: Откройте в браузере сетевую панель и посмотрите, откуда он пытается грузить иконки. Попробуйте открыть эти ссылки вручную и проверить, есть ли по данному адресу изображение.

Comment: За ответ большое спасибо, НО проблема в том что я сижу с ipad а компу ещё не скоро доберусь. И кстати где находится сетевая панель (например: в хроме)?

Comment: @Perkovec, в Хроме -- вот [тут][1].


  [1]: http://cs408218.vk.me/v408218798/4149/YaAPP7HRLhE.jpg

Comment: Спасибо уже всё сделал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Значит неправильно указал путь!

Comment: Повтопяю что все кнопки и переходы, короче всё показывает првильно но иконки нет.

Comment: покажите сайт откуда брали код!

Comment: http://jquerymobile.com/download/ версия 1.1.2